# toggleClass on IE won't work with mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, toggleclass

I have a problem with mobile menu on IE. I have a jquery script which open a mobile menu, simple script which add class to navigation. It works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari but not working on IE. Below you can see the code:

```
header nav ul {
overflow: hidden;
background: #505050;
height: 0;

header nav ul.open {
height: auto;
padding: 0;
```

and menu.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
    $("header nav ul").toggleClass("open");
});
```

});

I have tried with addClass, $(document).ready(function() and still doesn't work.

U can see this menu on eurolaserclinic.pl

Comment: I don't think there would ever be a time that a mobile menu is needed to work on IE?

Comment: Windows Mobile using IE

Comment: It happens that i own windows 8 phone and i did some tests on it. Actually the toggleClass is working as intented, the class is being changed, however the css styles are not applied (repainted) after the first change. A simple workaround would be to just use .toggle() on the menu, also in the css replace height: 0 with display: none. Tested and it worked on my ie phone. Lets hope someone else has any idea why styles are not reapplied on mobile ie.